# how to use syslog to avoid log file being garbled when multiple proceses are trying to write to the same log fille?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I wanted to know usage of syslog when multple processes are trying to write to the same log file like

```
for i in $var
do
some process >> logfile &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
some process | logger &
```

to spawn processes and have their output directed to syslog. Notice that the default facility will be “user” and the default level “notice”. You can change them using the `-p` option.

The reason why this works without probelm is that the processes don't directly write to the destination file. They send their messages to the syslog daemon, which manages writing to the appropriate file(s). As far as I understand things, the atomicity would be line-based, i.e. every line of output from a process would go to syslog without interference, but multi-line messages might get lines from other processes mixed in.

Comment: Thanks@MvG can you provide some more info, i dont understand how it would work when multiple proceses wud be trying to write to the same file at the same time